# phpUnit fails asserting that null is an instance of class "Zend \View\Model\ViewModel"

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, phpunit

I am new to phpunit-testing and Zend framework. I have been getting this error while doing a basic test:

```
Failed asserting that null is an instance of class "Zend\View\Model\ViewModel"
```

My test looks like this:

```
public function testFooActionCanBeAccessed()
{
    $mockView = $this->getMockBuilder('pathTo\Model\View\MyView', 
    array('getFooView'))
                    ->disableOriginalConstructor()
                    ->getMock();

    $mockUser = $this->getMockBuilder('pathTo\Entity\User')
                    ->disableOriginalConstructor()
                    ->getMock();

    $view = new ViewModel(array());

    $mockView->expects($this->once())
            ->method('getFooView')
            ->with($mockUser)
            ->will($this->returnValue($view));

    $this->routeMatch->setParam('action', 'foo');

    $result = $this->dispatch('/mycontroller/foo');

    $response = $this->controller->getResponse();
    $this->assertEquals(200, $response->getStatusCode());

    $this->assertInstanceOf('Zend\View\Model\ViewModel', $result);

}
```

The method under testing looks like this:

```
public function fooAction() {
    $user = $this->zfcUserAuthentication()->getIdentity();

    $myView = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('pathTo\Model\View\myView');
    $view = $myView->getFooView($user);

    return $view;
}
```

My setUp looks like this:

```
public function setUp()
{
        $serviceManager = Bootstrap::getServiceManager();
        $this->controller = new MyController();
        $this->request    = new Request();
        $this->response    = new Response;
        $this->routeMatch = new RouteMatch
        (array('controller' =>  'pathTo\Controller\My'));
        $this->event      = new MvcEvent();
        $config = $serviceManager->get('Config');
        $this->event->setRouteMatch($this->routeMatch);
        $this->controller->setEvent($this->event);
        $this->controller->setServiceLocator($serviceManager);
        $this->setApplicationConfig(
        include '/pathTo/config/testing.php');

        $mockAuth = $this->getMock('ZfcUser\Entity\UserInterface');

        $ZfcUserMock = $this->getMock('ZfcUser\Entity\User');  

        $ZfcUserMock->expects($this->any())
                    ->method('getId')
                    ->will($this->returnValue('1'));

        $authMock = $this->getMock('ZfcUser\Controller\Plugin\ZfcUserAuthentication');

        $authMock->expects($this->any())
                ->method('hasIdentity')
                -> will($this->returnValue(true));  

        $authMock->expects($this->any())
                ->method('getIdentity')
                ->will($this->returnValue($ZfcUserMock));

        $this->controller->getPluginManager()
        ->setService('zfcUserAuthentication', $authMock);


        $this->em = $this->getMock('EntityManager', array('persist', 'flush'));
        $this->em
            ->expects($this->any())
            ->method('persist')
            ->will($this->returnValue(true));
        $this->em
            ->expects($this->any())
            ->method('flush')
            ->will($this->returnValue(true));
        $this->doctrine = $this->getMock('Doctrine', array('getEntityManager'));
        $this->doctrine
            ->expects($this->any())
            ->method('getEntityManager')
            ->will($this->returnValue($this->em));

        parent::setUp();
}
```

So what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

The `dispatch` method returns null by design.  It just calls the page, similar to what you are doing when viewing the page in your browser.  It doesn't return a view model.

https://github.com/zendframework/zend-test/blob/master/test/PHPUnit/Controller/AbstractControllerTestCaseTest.php

In your test, you want to check what is actually in the view.  Use `$this->getResponse()` and check the state of the response that comes back.  The response will also have a `getContent()` method that you can use to check the html or json string that comes back and make sure that the right data is being displayed in the view.

Treat the controller test like you were bringing up the page in your browser.  What would you look for on the page to make sure that things were working properly?

***ALSO:***

In your test, you are not injecting your mockUser anywhere so your test will still fail because your `$mockView` will not be called with the `$mockUser` like you are expecting.  You will need to either change your `with()` paramter to be an instance of `ZfcUser\Entity\User` which is what it looks like you are actually getting in your `setUp` method or modify your tests so that your `$mockUser` is the one that actually gets returned from `$this->zfcUserAuthentication()->getIdentity();`

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I used getContent to check the html and it gives me 404 at the moment. Can you give me an example of injecting?

Comment: The file can be view in https://github.com/zendframework/zend-test/blob/master/test/PHPUnit/Controller/AbstractControllerTestCaseTest.php